# Make UITextfield accept only Katakana characters - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want my UITextField to accept only **one character** and it should be a **Katakana character**. How do I do it when user is typing with `Japanese-Romaji` phonetic keyboard?

`General->Keyboard->Keyboards-> Japanese Romaji`

Following code doesn't work since I get english characters to `string` param. It seems I have to deal with `markedTextRange` attribute of the textFiled, but not sure how. Any idea how to modify below method to fulfil my requirement?

> Multistage text input is a requirement when the language is ideographic and the keyboard is phonetic.

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if string.rangeOfCharacter(from: .init(charactersIn: "アイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲン")) != nil || string == ""{
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've noticed that you did not include all the Katakana in your list, such as those with ゛ and ゜, and the small versions of ヤ,ユ,ヨ,ツ (i.e. ャ,ュ,ョ,ッ) Is that intentional?

Comment: I got above character list from my client and we use them for a very specific drawing function in our app. So I hope we don't need to consider small versions. Thank you for noticing that ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observations, `markedTextRange` doesn't update until after `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called. Let's say I enter an `s`, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called first, then `markedTextRange` gets updated. This means it's really hard to distinguish between "entering the first 's' on an English keyboard" and "entering the first 's' on the Romaji keyboard", the former of which we want to disallow. In both cases, `markedTextRange` is nil in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Therefore, I think it would be easier if you do it on `editingChanged` instead:

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)

...

let katakanas =
    "アイウエオカキクケコサシスセソタチツテトナニヌネノハヒフヘホマミムメモヤユヨラリルレロワヲン"
@objc func textFieldChanged() {
    let newString = textfield.text ?? ""
    if !(newString.count == 1 &&
            katakanas.contains(newString.first!)) && textfield.markedTextRange == nil {
        // perhaps show an error alert here too
        textfield.text = ""
    }
}
```

This gets called only after the text changes and `markedTextRange` gets updated, so the `textfield.markedTextRange == nil` check will work correctly. Setting the entire text field to blank in case the user enters something invalid shouldn't be too bad of a UX, as you only meant to accept one character anyway.

You can still use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` to prevent users from entering further letters after there is already one katakana:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if let firstChar = textField.text?.first,
       katakanas.contains(firstChar) && string != "" {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tested with your textFieldChanged() function. When I typed `a` with English keyboard, `textfield.markedTextRange` is nil and therefore `textfield.text = ""` was invoked as expected  . But when I typed `a` with Romaji keyboard, `textfield.markedTextRange` is not nil and `あ` was inserted into the textField (which is not a katakana). Not sure why `textfield.markedTextRange` is not nil 

Comment: @S.Basnagoda That is expected. `textFieldChanged` is only called when you select an option from the list of options (when you unmark it). If you actually _select_ the あ option from the top part of the keyboard, the あ will disappear. You must allow あ to be entered into the text field as "marked text", because otherwise how would you ever type ア without あ? What my answer does is it disallows non-katakana that are _unmarked_.